Python Multithreading - Unterminated Processes
The code below, which I’ve modeled after the code I'm working on and simplified for the purpose of this question, doesn’t seems to be using p.join() properly to manage the processes created by p.start() As a result, there’s a memory leak, and the K8S pod where this code runs experiences resource exhaustion. Is there something obvious I’m missing?
import multiprocessing
import random
import time

def process_C(semaphore):
    try:
        sleep_time = random.random() * 6
        print("Process C sleeping for {:.2f} seconds".format(sleep_time))
        if sleep_time > 4.2:
            raise Exception("Random exception")
        time.sleep(sleep_time)
        print("Process C completed")
        semaphore.release()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Process C failed: {}".format(e))
        semaphore.release()


def process_B(semaphore):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_C, args=(semaphore,))
        semaphore.acquire()
        p.start()
        p.join(timeout=0)  # Set timeout to 0 to prevent blocking            
        print("Process B completed")
        
def process_A(semaphore):
        process_B(semaphore)    
        print("Process A completed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    semaphore = multiprocessing.Semaphore(20)
    while True:
        process_A(semaphore)


I tried checking if processes are alive and terminate them one by one with no success.

I'm sure that your p.join(timeout=0) does nothing. This means that your main thread will lose references to the processes leaving them unjoined and leaking. I think you need to collect them and join them later.

Can you explain why you're using semaphores? If you're trying to limit the number of concurrent processes, use a process pool for an easier life

The primary issue is that p.join(timeout=0) doesn't wait for the process to complete.
It immediately returns and moves on to the next loop iteration, causing zombie processes and resulting in a memory leak.
To check if processes are alive and terminate them if they are, you should keep track of each child's processes.
You could append each child process to a list, check if each one is alive, and then terminate them.
def process_B(semaphore, list_of_child_processes):
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_C, args=(semaphore,))
    semaphore.acquire()
    p.start()
    list_of_child_processes.append(p)  # Keep track of child processes
    print("Process B completed")

def process_A(semaphore, list_of_child_processes):
    process_B(semaphore, list_of_child_processes)

def terminate_processes(list_of_child_processes):
    """
    Call this function to terminate a process if it's alive

    """
    
    for p in list_of_child_processes:
        if p.is_alive():
            print("Terminating process:", p.pid)
            p.terminate()

Then
if __name__ == "__main__":
    semaphore = multiprocessing.Semaphore(20)
    list_of_child_processes = []
    while True:
        process_A(semaphore, list_of_child_processes)

Depends on the application you are running on a pod, you can decide how to call the terminate_processes function.
